# "The man in glasses" or "The man with glasses"?

Tags: differences, prepositions, colloquialisms

> The man **in** glasses

or

> The man **with** glasses

Is it grammatically correct to say *with* or *in* glasses? I've heard both, but the first seems to prevail a little bit more, though.

Googling didn't help a lot, I found one discussion only (*) where many native speakers said 'in glasses' didn't sound strange, yet they'd use 'with glasses'.

*
http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2499988

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Before we can answer, we'd need to know why you think one or the other is incorrect. Whether a person, a view, or whiskey, either *with* or *in* can be perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks. Native speakers tend to use with glasses on this forum http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2499988 , that's only why. I personally heard both. Wanted to know if there's a difference in terms of strict language usage and rules.

Comment: In the UK, I'd say _wearing glasses_ outperforms _with glasses_, which outperforms _in glasses_. That's not supported by [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wearing+glasses%2Cwith+glasses%2Cin+glasses.&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwearing%20glasses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20glasses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20glasses%20.%3B%2Cc0), though. But _in glasses_ comes consistently last, with the Google US corpus also.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am extremely sceptical of Google Ngrams, especially as regards British usage. No one has yet told me who audits this information. Like you I feel sure that *wearing glasses* would significantly outperform *with glasses* in the UK.

Comment: @WS2 Yes; I don't think they address the spoken word directly, which will really skew results.

Comment: I cannot tell what the question is here.

Comment: I put my teeth in a glass.  Does that count?

Comment: @tchrist I've edited the post. I was clueless until I read the comments.

Comment: Google Books yields 95,000 for [man **with** glasses](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22man+with+glasses%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=IzMCVcHDHIL5ygOZ_4HgBg#q=%22man+with+glasses%22&tbm=bks) but only  4,720 for [man **in** glasses](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22man+with+glasses%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=IzMCVcHDHIL5ygOZ_4HgBg#tbm=bks&q=%22man+in+glasses%22)

Comment: [Man **wearing** glasses](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22man+with+glasses%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=IzMCVcHDHIL5ygOZ_4HgBg#tbm=bks&q=%22man+wearing+glasses%22) produces 22,900 results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either is correct.  As others have commented, "with" seems more common than "in".

I would suggest that unless you want to imply that the glasses are the only distinguishing feature of a person, stick with "wearing" or "with" for glasses—reserve "in" for items of clothing, which do a better job of enclosing/obscuring at least a part of a person.

Not that it wouldn't be a perfectly acceptable compliment to say "You look good in glasses."

(hmmmm... Is there anywhere that people still call them "spectacles" or "specs"?)

Comment: Don't know about spectacles or specs, but I've heard people referring to glasses--particularly reading glasses--as "cheaters." Don